# An issue with Apple devices playing mp4 containers that have HE-AAC audio coding

Tags: ios, compression, aac, video-compression, handbrake

I'm not a pro in how to use codecs compared to other people I've seen, but I'm good enough to be able to compress videos decently.

I use HandBrake for the video but since HandBrake isn't very good with AAC compressing (at least from what I've tried) I use Premiere Pro instead since it supports HE-AAC and Parametric Stereo. Whenever I compress a video I start by encoding the audio in Premiere Pro with HE-AAC v2 parametric stereo, open Avidemux to put the output of the .aac file into the original file, then open HandBrake and put the audio settings on Auto Passthru.

However, I have realized that on any Apple device I've seen so far, the audio is way worse than it should be. I'm not sure if it's because it's an MP4 container, because of Avidemux, because I've been using H.264 (next time I compress something I'll use H.265), or because it just won't work whatsoever on Apple Devices no matter what. Any ideas?

Also, an example of a video that has been compressed that has the same audio issue: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/775102275546644511/873636072402325524/The_heavy_is_dead.mp4

Answer (score 1):

Try M4V container, it worked for me. And make sure to use h.265 10bit.  The 10bit option / version does a VERY good job with the video part. I did a lot of research. Bottom line, Super great compression quality with how the algorithm handles color and spatial translations on the video side of things.  I think the M4V container will fix your audio quality and compatibility issues too. Also, I had to get the HE-AAC HD.dll file from github and replace the one that is in the handbrake folder because HE-AAC was removed in the normal build due to licensing issues. If you type back to me here then I can give instructions on how to get the correct updated hd.dll file that has the correct HE-AAC (FDK) version with the high audio quality algorithm.  Then you can do it all in one step all within Handbrake.

Comment: I actually found the issue, the issue is that Premiere Pro's HE-AAC encoders either don't work properly or just use a method that's not supported on Apple devices. I tried using the encoders on a program named EZ CD Audio Converter and it worked well, and in most cases did an overall better job than Premiere Pro did, both with the Pro version and the Free version.